# ISE Design Suite simulation problem

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, ise

I am new in Verilog language. I am trying to understand the basics. There is this question where the input is a 6-bit number named `IN` and the output is a 1-bit number named `OUT`. When `IN` < 29, `OUT` is one. Otherwise `OUT` is zero. I have already written the code, and I am sure it is correct; however the simulation does not show anything. I have been trying to figure out what's wrong for a while now. I would appreciate any help I can get with this. My testbench goes until `IN` = 6'd29;.

```vhdl
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps

module lab1(input [5:0]IN, output reg OUT);

     always @ (IN)
     begin
        if (IN < 6'd29)
            OUT = 1'b1;
        else
            OUT = 1'b0;
        end
    //assign OUT = ~IN[5] & ~IN[4] | ~IN[5] & ~IN[3] | ~IN[5] & ~IN[2] | ~IN[5] & ~IN[1];
    //assign OUT = (IN < 6'd25) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
endmodule
```

```vhdl
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module lab1_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg IN;

    // Outputs
    wire OUT;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    lab1 uut (
        .IN(IN), 
        .OUT(OUT)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        IN = 6'd0;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd1;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd2;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd3;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd4;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd5;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd6;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd7;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd8;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd9;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd10;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd11;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd12;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd13;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd14;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd15;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd16;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd17;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd18;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd19;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd20;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd21;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd22;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd23;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd24;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd25;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd26;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd27;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd28;
        #10;
        IN = 6'd29;
        #10;
    end
    
        
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many simulators generate a warning message for your code.  For example, on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/vXQG), I see:

```
        .IN(IN), 
             |
xmelab: *W,CUVMPW (./testbench.sv,14|13): port sizes differ in port connection(1/6) for the instance(lab1_tb) .
```

The solution is to change:

```
reg IN;
```

to:

```
reg [5:0] IN;
```

Perhaps your simulator does generate a warning, but it wasn't obvious to you where you should look for it.  Note that your code is legal Verilog syntax, which is why you do not get an error.

---

Here is a more compact way of writing your code, using a `for` loop for the input:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module lab1 (input [5:0] IN, output OUT);
    assign OUT = (IN < 6'd25);
endmodule

module lab1_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg [5:0] IN;

    // Outputs
    wire OUT;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    lab1 uut (
        .IN(IN), 
        .OUT(OUT)
    );

    integer i;

  initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    for (i=0; i<30; i=i+1) begin
        IN = i;
        #10;
    end
  end
          
endmodule
```